# Using phpmyadmin to manage duplicates

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to easily manage duplicate entries in the MySQL database.

In a sense, I don't want to make my columns 'UNIQUE', but I want to review the records that happen to have exactly the same value in a column.

It would be nice if I could craft such an SQL query that shows only such records using the usual interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get duplicates, just use a self-join on the table :

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.value
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.value=t2.value
where t1.id < t2.id
```

The t1.id < t2.id will make sure every duplicate will only appear once.

Comment: Devious, but brilliant! Now I'm torn between awarding 'answer' to you or to hollsk!

Answer (score 3):

Should be possible to select them with a query:

```
select myColumn, count(myColumn) as myCount from myTable group by myColumn having myCount > 1 order by myCount;
```

Comment: Almost perfect! Could you share two more tidbits:

1) Getting to see all the records that happen to share the same myColumn value, instead of just the first one?

2) Getting to group by a combination of columns?

Comment: hm - the above code should return all duplicates as is. What number does count() give you? Also group by extra colums just by adding another column name with a comma - 'group by myColumn, myOthercolumn having...'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the interface, but this tool certainly does the former: http://www.dodownload.com/business+manage/access+database/mysql+delete+remove+duplicate+entries+software.html

Answer (score 0):

In wimvds answer above; phpMyAdmin shows the following warning:

Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

To enable edit/copy/delete, the first line can be changed to either:

```
select t1.id, t1.value
```

or

```
select t2.id, t2.value
```

Hence you may want to use wimvds's query to review duplicates (maybe along with other fields), then the second query to edit or delete duplicate records.

(Perhaps there is also a way to list duplicates; in adjacent rows, and editable?)